# JS prototyping Cannot set property 'moveRight' of undefined

Tags: javascript, class, properties, prototype, undefined

I've a problem with this simple prototyping:

```
Game = function (moduleConfig, gameConfig) {
    this.moduleConfig = moduleConfig;
    this.gameConfig = gameConfig;

    // Game-Commands
    this.keyCommands = {
        moveLeft: false,
        moveRight: false
    };

    this.catcher = null;
    this.stage = null;
    return this;
}

/**
 * Left arrow down
 */
Game.prototype.onKeyboardLeftDown = function () {
    this.keyCommands.moveLeft = true;
}

/**
 * Left arrow up
 */
Game.prototype.onKeyboardLeftUp = function () {
    this.keyCommands.moveLeft = false;
}
```

I always get the error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'moveRight' of undefined` when calling `onKeyboardLeftDown` and `onKeyboardLeftUp`. But i have declared `moveLeft` in the constructor in the `keyCommands` object.

The two methods were called on key down and key up events:

```
Game.prototype.init = function () {

    // ...

    // =========================================================================
    // Set keyboard
    KeyboardJS.on('left', this.onKeyboardLeftDown, this.onKeyboardLeftUp);
    KeyboardJS.on('right', this.onKeyboardRightDown, this.onKeyboardRightUp);
    // =========================================================================
};
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>pixi.js example 1</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="js/pixi.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="js/keyboard.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moduleConfig.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moduleResult.js"></script>
    <script src="js/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #EEEEEE">
    <script>

        var game = new Game(moduleConfig, {
            screenWidth: (window.innerWidth - 10),
            screenHeight: (window.innerHeight - 10),
            bgColor: 0xEEEEEE
        });

        game.init();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Does some one see the failure? I have searched a lot, but i'm very confused (normally i develop only in c#...)

Comment: My guess: 'this' is bound to window?

Comment: Why is this bound to window?

Comment: Your binding is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding is wrong.

```
// Set keyboard
KeyboardJS.on('left', this.onKeyboardLeftDown, this.onKeyboardLeftUp);
```

`this.onKeyboardLeftDown` and `this.onKeyboardLeftUp` are called without the correct context

to fix this do something like:

```
KeyboardJS.on('left', this.onKeyboardLeftDown.bind(Game), this.onKeyboardLeftUp.bind(Game));
```

I would not recommend using bind() - for browser compatibility, but you can use something like lodash's bind or an bind "emulator" like:

```
function bind(fn, ctx) {
    return function bound() {
        return fn.apply(ctx, arguments);
    };
}
```

Another way would be

```
var self = this;
KeyboardJS.on('left', 
    function(){self.onKeyboardLeftDown()}, 
    function(){self.onKeyboardLeftUp()}
);
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the alternative to bind, if it is not recommended?

Comment: well i would avoid either of those, and do a anonymous function that would invoke this function as its the fastest way however libraries like lodash, or simply search for bind emulator

Comment: You can (however) bind this with this thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: You cannot bind it with call, as call invokes the function as well

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not complete, I do not see the relevant code where you try to define `moveRight`.

Possible problems:

- you might have a typo, that `keyCommands` is spelled exactly
- you might refer to `keyCommands` outside its scope
- you might refer to `keyCommands.moveRight` before `keyCommands` is initialized
- you might assign another value to `keyCommands` before referring to `moveRight`

Comment: Hmm, keyCommands/moveRight is defined in the ctor. Or is that wrong? I've tried to put all commands in a simple json object

Comment: Can you console.log(keyCommands) just before you use it? Is it undefined? Then it was not initialized yet. You must make sure that when when you use it, it already exists.

Comment: If i use `console.log(this.keyCommands);`, it returns undefined. But so the context seems to be wrong.

Comment: This is the point of my answer. keyCommands is undefined where you try to use it, thus, one of the potential problems mentioned in my answer could be matching your problem.